# how to populate two multi select checkbox list in Ext js

Tags: extjs

We have two multi select checkbox list in extjs 2.3, Country and state.

How to populate second according to first? Suppose we select India then second checkbox list should be sort according to first list.

Comment: did you say extjs 2.3

Comment: Yes, its extjs 2.3

Comment: there is no fiddle for 2.3 , I can try in 3.4. Will post the fiddle in some time.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a 'change' listener to the first checkboxgroup. This listener gives the array of checked boxes as a parameter. You can loop through the array to find the checked countries and sort the second checkbox group accordingly.

[checkboxgroup change event listner](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-event-change)

Comment: Please do not ad link only answers, please copy the essential parts of the answer from the link as the links might change in future.